# Add columns to dataframe that are not already in another dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add empty columns to a dataframe df1 that are not already in a second dataframe df2. So, given

```
df2.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df1.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

I would like to add columns with names 'c' and 'd' to dataframe df1.

For performance reasons, I would like to *avoid* a loop with multiple `withColumn()` statements:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in df2.columns:
        df1= df1.withColumn(col, lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

My first attemt

```
df1 = df1.select(col('*'),
                 lit(None).alias(col_name) for col_name in df1.columns if col_name not in df2.columns)
```

is throwing an error

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <generator object
> myfunction.. at 0x7f60e2bcc8e0> of type <class
> 'generator'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or
> 'create_map' function.

Comment: you are so close! as stated in mohona's answer below, the `lit(None).alias(col_name) for col_name in df1.columns if col_name not in df2.columns` should be within a list or anything that can be unpacked. the answer suggests the use of `list()`. you could also just enclose the aforementioned within `[]` (box brackets) and unpack it. `*[lit(None).alias(col_name) for col_name in df1.columns if col_name not in df2.columns]`. Option 2 is to enclose `col('*')` and generator within box brackets and join them using `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to convert `generator` to list using `list()` function.  After converting pass the list to `select()`.

```
df1.select(col('*'), *list(lit(None).alias(col_name) for col_name in df2.columns if col_name not in df1.columns))
```

Comment: this will return a dataframe with duplicate column names and throws Reference column is ambigious, when we try to access it by column name

Comment: Yes. But @Wasserwaage needs to explain what exactly he is trying to do. Whether he wants to add columns which are there in df2 not in df1 or present in df1 but not in df2.

Comment: Clarified question with example.